# Landscape orientation in iPad Pro

Tags: swift, ipad, orientation, landscape, portrait

I have created a program with a cover image which changes depending on the orientation: it displays a portrait image in portrait mode, and a landscape image in landscape mode. Everything is working fine in every iPhone & iPad simulators, but not in the iPad Pro simulator. Actually, the landscape mode does work, but instead of displaying the landscape cover image, it just adapts the height of the Portrait cover image to the new height in Landscape mode. I don't own an iPad Pro yet, so I don't know if it comes from the iPad Pro or the simulator. Does anyone have encountered this kind of problem? Is there some code to add specifically for iPad Pro?

Answer (score 2):

Without seeing your project, you might need to force your app to use the full screen. In the app target, try checking "Requires Full Screen" is enabled.

[image: Xcode fullscreen settings]

Comment: It worked, but it means the App won't be multi-screen. Is there no other way?

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing your code, but the details of the new protocols are here:


https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/AdoptingMultitaskingOniPad/QuickStartForSlideOverAndSplitView.html


When you require full-screen, you are opting out of split view.